# column ambiguously defined even though all the selected columns are prefixed, while creating view

Tags: oracle, view

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN
    AS
      SELECT PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.STATUS, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.TEST_EPOCH, DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN.*, OFFER_MSG_OFFERMESSAGE.TEXT AS OFFER_MSG_OFFERMESSAGE, NULL AS AWARD_MSG, REMINDER_MSG_REMINDERMESSAGE.TEXT AS REMINDER_MSG_REMINDERMESSAGE, PMM_PROGRAM.BASE_TIMEZONE, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_TEMPLATE, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.TASKS_SUBMITTED, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.TASKS_EVALUATED, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.TASKS_COMPLETED, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.EMITS, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.LAST_EVALUATION, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.LAST_PREEVALUATION, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.TARGET_LIST_JOB_STATUS, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.TARGET_LIST_TYPE, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.TARGET_LIST_ID, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.PENDING_TIME, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.STARTING_TIME, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.OFFERING_TIME, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.OPEN_TIME, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.SUSPENDED_TIME, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.COMPLETE_TIME, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.FAILED_TIME, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.KILLED_TIME, PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.LAST_UPDATE_TIME
      FROM
      DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN
      LEFT JOIN
      PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN
      ON PMM_UPSELL_CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGNID = DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGNID
      LEFT JOIN
      PMM_PROGRAM
      ON PMM_PROGRAM.PROGRAM_ID = DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN.PROGRAM_ID
      LEFT JOIN
      DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN_MSG OFFER_MSG_OFFERMESSAGE
      ON DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN.PROGRAM_ID = OFFER_MSG_OFFERMESSAGE.PROGRAM_ID
      AND DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGNID = OFFER_MSG_OFFERMESSAGE.CAMPAIGNID
      AND PMM_PROGRAM.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = OFFER_MSG_OFFERMESSAGE."LANGUAGE"
      AND OFFER_MSG_OFFERMESSAGE.MESSAGEID = 'NBO_SMS_OFFER'
      LEFT JOIN
      DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN_MSG OFFER_MSG_OFFERMESSAGE
      ON DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN.PROGRAM_ID = OFFER_MSG_OFFERMESSAGE.PROGRAM_ID
      AND DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGNID = OFFER_MSG_OFFERMESSAGE.CAMPAIGNID
      AND PMM_PROGRAM.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = OFFER_MSG_OFFERMESSAGE."LANGUAGE"
      AND OFFER_MSG_OFFERMESSAGE.MESSAGEID = 'NBO_SMS_AWARD'
      LEFT JOIN
      DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN_MSG REMINDER_MSG_REMINDERMESSAGE
      ON DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN.PROGRAM_ID = REMINDER_MSG_REMINDERMESSAGE.PROGRAM_ID
      AND DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGNID = REMINDER_MSG_REMINDERMESSAGE.CAMPAIGNID
      AND PMM_PROGRAM.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = REMINDER_MSG_REMINDERMESSAGE."LANGUAGE"
      AND REMINDER_MSG_REMINDERMESSAGE.MESSAGEID = 'NBO_SMS_REMINDER'
      ORDER BY DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN.SCHEDULED_DAY DESC, DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN.SCHEDULED_HOUR DESC, DU_NBO_CAMPAIGN.NAME ASC;
```

I get this error when running above in Sql Developer:-

> Error at Command Line:1 Column:0
>
> Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
>
> 00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

Comment: `du_nbo_campaign.*` is probably the cause of the issue - you probably have a column in du_nbo_campaign that's got the same name/alias elsewhere in your select statement. In general, don't use "select *" for production code, or, in your case, this view. You need to explicitly select the columns you're after from that table and alias them appropriately so you don't have two columns with the same name in your select.

Comment: No its not, I suspected it too and removed `du_nbo_campaign.*` from the view, still getting the same error

Comment: You have `du_nbo_campaign_msg` aliased as `offer_msg_offermessage` twice in your from clause. Try fixing that. Seems like one of the aliases should really be something like `award_msg_awardmessage`

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the fault...got it working now :) thanks

Comment: If you formatted the `select` clause nicely it would be easier to spot such mistakes maybe?

Comment: can you post the DDLs for the tables ?

Comment: no need @Massimo , its fixed with help of Boneist's comment